# Software which stores and "pastes" snippets running under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, snippets

I'm looking for a tool which can create, manage and store snippets. Moreover I want this tool can "write" snippets in any text-editor : notepad, SQL Server Management Studio, Visual Studio, Word etc. when typing shortcut.

For example,

- I create a new snippet in my tool :

  - Shortcut : .fch
  - Snippet : `foreach(var i in item) {}`

I open Notepad and Word: if I tape ".fch" in one of these editors the .fch sequence is replaced by the snippet.

I don't want a tool which works with drag'n'drop.

Is there a tool like this?

Comment: Safe to assume Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the one you want is [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com), it can create hotstring pretty fast and easy and it works exactly like you want.

Some example:

```
::.fch::foreach(var i in item) {}
```

Comment: I have a conflict with some soft with the TAB key, Is there any way to change the TAB key by another one ?

Comment: as default, you can use space, it expands too.

Comment: You can also use the hotstring macro to change the trigger characters
http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/_Hotstring.htm
`#Hotstring EndChars -()[]{}':;"/\,.?!`n `t`